# How to keep two MySQL databases of wordpress , AWS lightsail in sync?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have got my client who wants following :

1. 2 servers
2. load balancer
3. daily backup (30 days )
4. database synchronisation

Suppose I apply 2 lightsail instances and one network load balancer for hosting two identical wordpress commerce sites.

How to ensure the databases, images, and plugin of wordpress are in sync?  It is because the order created by one user at one site, shall be recorded at the another database.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a great use case for Lightsail (I'm the developer advocate for Lightsail, so you can trust me when I say that).

You need to understand how WordPress work with regards to storing various data. There is a bunch of stuff stored in MySQL but there is also a bunch of stuff stored on the file system (including plugins, uploaded media, etc).

So you could fire up to lightsail instances, point them at a single lightsail database (or self-hosted MySQL) but that doesn't solve the issue with keeping the local filesystem in sync across the various instances. Yo

What you would really want with AWS is something like cloud front (for caching) in front of a load balancer. The LB fronts multiple EC2 instances that run WP. They are connected to an RDS instance running MYSQL as well as using a shared EFS* volume to host the file system.**

You can't do this on Lightsail because there is no good way to use EFS with Lightsail (even with VPC peering).

*Some will argue that EFS/NFS is not fast enough for WordPress, but I've seen with the right caching etc it be pretty effective.

**This one approach another is to use S3 to store common media, but I don't think that handles the issue w/ plugins - so maybe you want a combination of s3 for media and EFS for plug ins

Comment: NIce answer. I have another one, How to disable and enable cache during development in Lightsail instance for wordpress linux. How many hours it will take to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler and essentially as reliable to host a third database server and point both WP installs there. In this case you would also be well served to set S3 offload and store uploads there.

TBH the db isn't your problem, keeping uploads, plugins and themes in sync is the more complicated issue

Comment: In that case, it seems two lightsails/EC2 does not matter. Pointing the RDS with configuration would work ?  

As for wordpress site synchronisation, how to ensure same domain going to Multisite?